# Vaadin on Google Cloud: Production Deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I've gone through https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/cloud-deployment/google to learn about how to deploy a Vaadin application on GCP.

Now, when I dive into the details, I see that Cloud Run doesn't support Session Affinity, and although Google App Engine does support it, the documentation says "You should never use session affinity to build stateful applications." So basically that means that what is suggested in the tutorial is not really working for production use.

So, my question is, what is the recommended approach to run Vaadin application on Google Cloud for production deployments?

I read that a distributed session store is also not on option (https://vaadin.com/blog/session-replication-in-the-world-of-vaadin).

Thank you,
Kristof.

Answer (score 0):

Using any Vaadin (except Fusion maybe) relies on heavy use of server side stored state in a session (a massive scene graph is stored per client) -- there is no way around it. If your environment or use-case can not cope with this, then you are better off *not* using Vaadin.  Due to the size of the session data, using a distributed session store *without* session affinity is *discouraged* (and the linked blog shows why).

TL;DR: there are no silver bullets.

Answer (score 0):

A late response but could be useful for others.

Vaadin is not really cloud friendly.

There are demo on the vaadin site about server side stored session with hazelcast ... but after the first 'great it works' and a few days of effort and research you realise

1. it is not really more than a hello world and others developers having tried this way faced multiple blocking issues with no answers
2. this server side stored session endup with something much too heavy for a large scale deployment.
3. as cfrick mentioned, this required anyway session affinity for performance reasons

So my view is : forget it, sticky session is the only way with vaadin.

Now sticky session is not so straight forward to setup first especially when using push then to go production, you also need to manage things like "app ready" and "app gone" ... and up to now, I've not seen any production grade response.